# Convert labels to Annotation addin crashes ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, c#, labeling, .net

I am trying to write an ArcMap (10.3) Add-In in C# .NET that will convert labels to annotation. I have used a majority of the code from the relevant [snippet](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/00010000024r000000.htm) on the ESRI resources website. When I run the code ArcMap just crashes.

I am running:

- Visual Studio 2012
- Developer Kit 10.3
- ArcMap 10.3 (Advanced license level)

Also, I have intermediate experience with Python and ArcPy, but this is my first attempt at using my novice C# skills with ArcMap, so beware of my code.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase;


namespace ConvertLabelsToAnnotation
{
    public class labelToAnno : ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Button
    {
        public labelToAnno()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnClick()
        {
            IMxDocument mxdoc = ArcMap.Application.Document as IMxDocument;
            IMap pMap = mxdoc.FocusMap as IMap;
            bool featureLinked = true;
            IConvertLabelsToAnnotation pConvertLabelsToAnnotation = new
                ConvertLabelsToAnnotationClass();
            ITrackCancel pTrackCancel = new TrackCancel();

            pConvertLabelsToAnnotation.Initialize(pMap,
                esriAnnotationStorageType.esriDatabaseAnnotation,
                esriLabelWhichFeatures.esriAllFeatures, true, pTrackCancel);

            IEnumLayer pEnumLayer1 = pMap.Layers;
            ILayer pLayer;
            pLayer = pEnumLayer1.Next();


            IAnnotateLayerProperties pAnnotateLayerProperties = new LabelEngineLayerPropertiesClass();
            IFeatureLayer pFeatLayer = pLayer as IFeatureLayer;
            pAnnotateLayerProperties.FeatureLayer = pFeatLayer;
            pAnnotateLayerProperties.DisplayAnnotation = false;

            IGeoFeatureLayer pGeoFeatureLayer = pLayer as IGeoFeatureLayer;
            if (pGeoFeatureLayer != null)
            {
                IFeatureClass pFeatureClass = pGeoFeatureLayer.FeatureClass;

                IDataset pDataset = pFeatureClass as IDataset;

                IFeatureWorkspace pFeatureWorkspace = pDataset.Workspace as
                    IFeatureWorkspace;

                pConvertLabelsToAnnotation.AddFeatureLayer(pGeoFeatureLayer,
                    pGeoFeatureLayer.Name + "_Anno", pFeatureWorkspace,
                    pFeatureClass.FeatureDataset, featureLinked, false, false, true, true, 
                    "");

                //Do the conversion.
                pConvertLabelsToAnnotation.ConvertLabels();
                IEnumLayer pEnumLayer = pConvertLabelsToAnnotation.AnnoLayers;
                //Turn off labeling for the layer converted.
                pGeoFeatureLayer.DisplayAnnotation = false;

                //Add the result annotation layer to the map.
                pMap.AddLayers(pEnumLayer, true);

                //Refresh the map to update the display.
                IActiveView pActiveView = pMap as IActiveView;
                pActiveView.Refresh();
            }
        }
        protected override void OnUpdate()
        {
            Enabled = ArcMap.Application != null;
        }
    }

}
```

I am struggling to see where I have gone wrong. Perhaps some more experienced eyes can suggest something. One thing that did come to mind is that the anno feature classes aren't being put into a gdb, at least as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I've solved this question myself.

The requirement was to send the annotation data to an annotation feature class within a GDB. Whilst I am yet to be able to create GDB and FCs with ArcObjects, I created these manually and then created the pointer variables that accepted the annotation data. Consequently, ArcMap did not fall over and produced the desired result.

Here is my amended code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.DataSourcesGDB;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Display;

namespace ConvertLabelsToAnnotation
{
    public class labelToAnno : ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Button
    {
        public labelToAnno()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnClick()
        {
            IMxDocument mxdoc = ArcMap.Application.Document as IMxDocument;
            IMap pMap = mxdoc.FocusMap as IMap;
            pMap.MapUnits = esriUnits.esriMeters;

            IWorkspaceFactory2 wsf = new FileGDBWorkspaceFactoryClass();

            string gdbPath = @"C:\Users\pathname";
            IWorkspace ws = wsf.OpenFromFile(gdbPath, ArcMap.Application.hWnd);

            IFeatureWorkspace fws = ws as IFeatureWorkspace;
            IFeatureClass fc = fws.OpenFeatureClass("anno");

            bool featureLinked = true;
            IConvertLabelsToAnnotation pConvertLabelsToAnnotation = new
                ConvertLabelsToAnnotationClass();
            ITrackCancel pTrackCancel = new TrackCancel();
            //Change global level options for the conversion by sending in different parameters to the next line.
            pConvertLabelsToAnnotation.Initialize(pMap,
                esriAnnotationStorageType.esriDatabaseAnnotation,
                esriLabelWhichFeatures.esriAllFeatures, true, pTrackCancel);

            //IEnumLayer pEnumLayer1 = pMap.Layers;
            IFeatureLayer pFeatLayer = new FeatureLayerClass();
            pFeatLayer.Name = "Anno_layer";
            pFeatLayer.FeatureClass = fc;
            //pLayer = pEnumLayer1.Next();


            IAnnotateLayerProperties pAnnotateLayerProperties = new LabelEngineLayerPropertiesClass();
            //IFeatureLayer pFeatLayer = pLayer as IFeatureLayer;
            pAnnotateLayerProperties.FeatureLayer = pFeatLayer;
            pAnnotateLayerProperties.DisplayAnnotation = true;

            IGeoFeatureLayer pGeoFeatureLayer = pFeatLayer as IGeoFeatureLayer;
            if (pGeoFeatureLayer != null)
            {
                IFeatureClass pFeatureClass = pGeoFeatureLayer.FeatureClass;

                IDataset pDataset = pFeatureClass as IDataset;

                IFeatureWorkspace pFeatureWorkspace = pDataset.Workspace as
                    IFeatureWorkspace;
                //Add the layer information to the converter object. Specify the parameters of the output annotation feature class here as well.
                pConvertLabelsToAnnotation.AddFeatureLayer(pFeatLayer,
                    pGeoFeatureLayer.Name + "_Anno", pFeatureWorkspace,
                    pFeatureClass.FeatureDataset, featureLinked, false, false, true, true, 
                    "");

                //Do the conversion.
                pConvertLabelsToAnnotation.ConvertLabels();
                IEnumLayer pEnumLayer = pConvertLabelsToAnnotation.AnnoLayers;
                //Turn off labeling for the layer converted.
                pGeoFeatureLayer.DisplayAnnotation = false;

                //Add the result annotation layer to the map.
                pMap.AddLayers(pEnumLayer, true);

                //Refresh the map to update the display.
                IActiveView pActiveView = pMap as IActiveView;
                pActiveView.Refresh();
            }
        }
        protected override void OnUpdate()
        {
            Enabled = ArcMap.Application != null;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you say you have some experience in Python, I believe what you are trying to do could be accomplished with a Python Add-In (I'm not well versed in ArcObjects and C#).  I have a jankety workaround function that I call in other scripts that will generate annotation feature classes (always for a soils data set) based on a project boundary.

The way this works is I have a dummy mxd and file geodatabase set up on one of our NAS boxes where I replace the feature class in the gdb which the mxd is sourced to.  I then use the [Tiled Labels to Annotation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//007000000007000000) tool to pass in a project boundary and an annotation feature class is created within that boundary.

So you could create a Python Add-In with two comboboxes (one with the layer name, the other that has a field list dropdown once a layer has been chosen) and a button to create annotation from that layer.  As for the boundary extent, you can create a [Polygon](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z00000061000000) from either the data frame extent or the extent of that layer's datasource.  Here is the function I use that could be modified and called in a Python Add-In:

```
import arcpy, os, time
from arcpy import mapping as m
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

def CreateAnnotationFC(in_fc, soils):
    gdb = r'\\Ns0113x1g2737\gis\SWPPP\_County_MN\Geodatabase\Annotation.gdb'
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(in_fc, os.path.join(gdb, 'Project_Boundary'))
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(soils, os.path.join(gdb, 'Soils'))
    time.sleep(2)  # Give it time to release schema locks
    anno_lyr = r'\\Ns0113x1g2737\gis\SWPPP\_County_MN\Geodatabase\GroupLayer.lyr'

    # delete Annotation feature class
    anno = os.path.join(gdb, 'SoilsAnno6000')
    if arcpy.Exists(anno):
        arcpy.Delete_management(anno)

    # set up mxd
    if arcpy.GetInstallInfo()['Version'] == '10.0':
        mapDoc = r'\\NS0113X1G2737\gis\SWPPP\_County_MN\MXD\SoilsTemplate_v10.mxd'
    else:
        mapDoc = r'\\NS0113X1G2737\gis\SWPPP\_County_MN\MXD\SoilsTemplate_v10_1.mxd'
    mxd = m.MapDocument(mapDoc)
    df = m.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
    df_name = df.name
    df.spatialReference = arcpy.Describe(in_fc).spatialReference
    for lyr in m.ListLayers(mxd,'*',df):
        if lyr.name == 'Soils':
            lyr.showLabels = True # always make sure this is on
            where = '{0} IS NOT NULL'.format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(lyr.dataSource,arcpy.Describe(lyr.dataSource).OIDFieldName))
            arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(lyr,'NEW_SELECTION',where)
            df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()
            arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(lyr,'CLEAR_SELECTION',where)                          

        # Remove Group Layers  
        if lyr.isGroupLayer:
            m.RemoveLayer(df,lyr)
            arcpy.AddMessage('Removed: %s' %lyr.name)
    df.scale = 6000
    mxd.save()
    del mxd

    # Create Annotation FC
    arcpy.TiledLabelsToAnnotation_cartography(mapDoc,df_name,os.path.join(gdb,'Project_Boundary'),gdb,anno_lyr,'Anno',
                                                         6000,'','','','','','GENERATE_UNPLACED_ANNOTATION')
    arcpy.AddMessage('Created Annotation Feature Class')
    return r'\\NS0113X1G2737\gis\SWPPP\_County_MN\Geodatabase\Annotation.gdb\SoilsAnno6000'


if __name__ ==  '__main__':

    bound = r'C:\TEMP\New_Points\Swppp_input.shp'
    soils = r'C:\TEMP\SWPPP_test\SWPPP_11_06_2013\Shapefiles\All_Soils.shp'

    # test   
    CreateAnnotationFC(bound, soils)
```

You may also want to include another combobox where the user can type in a scale for the annotation FC.